# How to retrieve images from server in android

Tags: android

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
         Bitmap bitmap = DownloadImage(
                    "http://www.animateit.net/data/media/nov2011/1590877-smiling_kid.gif");
                ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img);
                img.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            }

            private InputStream OpenHttpConnection(String urlString) 
            throws IOException
            {
                InputStream in = null;
                int response = -1;

                URL url = new URL(urlString); 
                URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();

                if (!(conn instanceof HttpURLConnection))                     
                    throw new IOException("Not an HTTP connection");

                try{
                    HttpURLConnection httpConn = (HttpURLConnection) conn;
                    httpConn.setAllowUserInteraction(false);
                    httpConn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
                    httpConn.setRequestMethod("GET");
                    httpConn.connect(); 

                    response = httpConn.getResponseCode();                 
                    if (response == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                        in = httpConn.getInputStream();                                 
                    }                     
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    throw new IOException("Error connecting");            
                }
                return in;     
            }
            private Bitmap DownloadImage(String URL)
            {        
                Bitmap bitmap = null;
                InputStream in = null;        
                try {
                    in = OpenHttpConnection(URL);
                    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
                    in.close();
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
                return bitmap;                
            }


    }
```

I need to retrieve image from server db.I have tried this code but not show result.Then this source are successfully run but not show images.i can't find errors anybody can help,why image are not showed and download.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple method that allows you to do that:

```
public static Bitmap decodeRemoteBitmap(String urlString) throws MalformedURLException, IOException{
    URL url = new URL(urlString);
    InputStream inputStream = url.openStream();
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
    return bitmap;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**the Issue in your code: load bitmap in thread not ui thread**

1- Add the bitmap load in Async task as following:

```
public class ImageLoader extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Bitmap>{

private ImageView img;
public ImageLoader(ImageView img) {
    this.img = img;
}

@Override
protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... params) {
    try {
        InputStream in = OpenHttpConnection(params[0]);
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
        in.close();
        return bitmap;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
    if (result != null)
        img.setImageBitmap(result);
    super.onPostExecute(result);
}
  }
```

2- Call the task as following:

```
ImageLoader loader = new ImageLoader(img);
loader.execute(URL);
```

**Other solution**
There is a lot of cases you have to handle when load image like outOfMemory and caching, use library and it will save time and bugs on you.

I use [Android-Universal-Image-Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader) it is simple, add the [jar](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader/raw/master/downloads/universal-image-loader-1.9.1.jar) file in lib folder then 
`ImageLoader.getInstance().init(config);`
`ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(imageUri, imageView);`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Android Universal Image Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader) as mentioned by Alex which particularly is my preferred one ([Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) is another option). However, recently I've encountered very specific problems with these libraries which led me to implement a simple image loader by myself using an Async Task:

```
public class ImageDownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {

    private final String imageURL;
    private final ImageView imageView;
    private final Context context;

    /**
     * Constructor
     * @param context
     * @param imageURL
     * @param imageView
     */
    public ImageDownloadTask(final Context context, final String imageURL, final ImageView imageView) {
        this.imageURL = imageURL;
        this.imageView = imageView;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(final String... args) {
        Bitmap bitmap = null;

        try {

                final InputStream in = new URL(imageURL).openStream();
                bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
                in.close();

        } catch (final Exception e) {
            Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
        }
        return bitmap;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(final Bitmap result) {
        if(result != null){
            imageView.setImageBitmap(result);
        }
    }
}
```

In an activity, you can use this class like this:

```
new ImageDownloadTask(this, pictureURL, surveyImage).execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a code:

```
                URL url = new URL(image);
                HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url
                .openConnection();
                 conn.setDoInput(true);
                 conn.connect();
                 InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
           bmImg = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
            imgdisplay.setImageBitmap(bmImg);
```

"image" is the imagepath.Also define a bitmap like `Bitmap bmImg = null;`